# How do I ask for GPS location permission to "ALLOW ALL THE TIME"?

Tags: android, gps, android-permissions, android-location, android-gps

I am trying to ask for the user to activate the GPS permission for my Android app.

There are two ways to do it:

1. When Android asks to allow or deny the permission.
2. When I have the user dig in to the app's setting and turn on the **Allow all the time** by himself.

In the app's permission settings - there's the **Allow all the time** option:

[image: GPS Setting screen].

How do I get "Allow all the time" to show up also in the permission pop up screen like in this screenshot?

[image: GPS Popup]

I already have the:

```
<uses-permission `android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION" />`
```

in my `Manifest` file.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/training/location/permissions

Comment: Thank you for your answer :-)